# angularjs $resource : can't $save JSON

Tags: rest, angularjs

starting with angular, i am trying to GET data from the server and then POST back modifications with $resources.

It's working fine except the "save" function. No Data is POSTed back to the server.

here is the html

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
<div ng-repeat="obj in objs">
    <h2>{{obj.data_1}}</h2>
    <h3>{{obj.data_2}}</h3>
    <input type='text' ng-model="obj.data_1"><br/>
    <textarea ng-model="obj.data_2" required></textarea><br/>
    <button ng-click="save()">Save</button>
</div>
</div>
```

service.js

```
'use strict';
angular.module('App.services', ['ngResource']).
factory('Obj', function($resource){
    return $resource('url/to/json');
});
```

controller.js:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('App.controllers', []).
controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'Obj', function($scope, Obj) {
    $scope.objs = Obj.query();
    $scope.save = function() {
        $scope.objs.save();
    }
}]);
```

Do you know why nothing is POSTed back when i save ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the query method on the $resource object implies return as follows `'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true}` it's mean that your `$scope.objs` is an array of objects and not an object and depending on number of elements you can use the folowing notation:

```
$scope.objs[i].save()
```

where i is the index of element in the array, forexample if you have return like:

```
[ {id:1, name:'Some name', age:35} ];
```

then your code : `$scope.objs[0].save()`

**Edit:**
I have created a plunk, maybe it will help you... http://plnkr.co/edit/62iPCAUNjV0oJROhul1G

Comment: thanks, but… when i do this, the console returns an error with : "TypeError: Object #<g> has no method 'save'". if I use "$save()" instead of "save()", the error is "TypeError: Object #<g> has no method 'push'"

Comment: i am progressing… The `$save()` seems to send POST informations. But the sent datas are not updated and there is still an error in the console `TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'`

Comment: @desgnl I have added a plunk, hope this will help

Comment: thanks a lot ! it's really clear and i am almost there. It's working but i am still having an error in the console. see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208861/angular-error-object-has-no-method-push

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't there be another `$resource` declared for POST the way it is declared for GET? Each `$resource` specify particular REST service.

```
//services.js
'use strict';
angular.module('App.services', ['ngResource'])
.factory('GetObj', function($resource){
    return $resource('url/to/json');
}
.factory('SaveObj', function($resource){
    return $resource('url/to/post');
});

//controller.js
'use strict';
angular.module('App.controllers', []).
controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'GetObj', 'SaveObj', function($scope, GetObj, SaveObj) {
    $scope.objs = Obj.query();
    $scope.save = SaveObj.save(objs, function(resp) {
        //Callback
        console.log("Response from POST: %j", resp);
    }
}]);
```

Comment: i tried this, but it triggered 2 GET and 2 POST on load, and nothing when the button is clicked. Looking at the doc, i am not sure it's necessary to declare another resource for save()