# angular error : object has no method push

Tags: rest, angularjs

I am trying to make a angular work with a REST service and `$resource`.

it works to GET the datas from JSON, but when updating whith `$save()` or a custom method called `$rec()`, i have an error in the console saying : `TypeError: Object #<c> has no method 'push'`.  Switching `isArray` to `true` or `false`, didn't change anything.

i made a plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/fS2bjRKPgUulTbTxgg2j

the error is visible when you make it run on your own server.

the html:

```
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="obj in objs">
        <div>
          <h3>{{obj.name}}</h3>
          <h3>{{obj.age}}</h3>
          <input type="text" ng-model="obj.name" /><br />
          <input type="text" ng-model="obj.age" /><br />
          <button ng-click="save(obj)">Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and the javascript:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('TestApp', ['TestApp.services', 'TestApp.controllers']);

angular.module('TestApp.services', ['ngResource']).
  factory('Obj', function($resource){
return $resource('datas.json', {}, { 'rec': {method: 'POST', isArray: true } });
});

angular.module('TestApp.controllers', []).
controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'Obj', function($scope, Obj) {
    $scope.objs = Obj.query();
    $scope.save = function(obj) {
        obj.$save();
            console.log(obj);
    }
}]);
```

do you know where the error comes from ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS $resource error - TypeError: Object #<g> has no method 'push'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15932422/angularjs-resource-error-typeerror-object-g-has-no-method-push)

Comment: you have defined your custom method `$rec` but why are you calling `$save`?

Comment: my case is different: there is an error when i am saving the datas not when i am getting them. I made a custom function '.$rec()' with an isArray parameter. but changing it from true to false didn't remove the error.

Comment: @akonsu i tried with both the standard `$save()` method and the custom `$rec()` method. the result is the same.

Comment: I do not see this error in plnkr. it gives me 404 when posting when I click "save".

Comment: @akonsu yes the error is not in plnkr, but when you download the files and make it run on your own server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have copied your plnkr to my dev machine, set up a sinatra site as below but I still do not see this error. the client posts a JSON string like `{"name"=>"louise", "age"=>"32"}` when I click on a blue button, and everything seems fine. Are you handling the `POST` appropriately?

here is my server code:

**app.ru**:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8; mode:ruby; -*-

require 'json'
require 'multi_json'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/json'

class App < Sinatra::Base
  helpers Sinatra::JSON

  get '/datas.json' do
    json([
          {"name" => "louise", "age" => "32"},
          {"name" => "jeanne", "age" => "25"},
          {"name" => "renée", "age" => "21"},
          {"name" => "fernande", "age" => "28"}
         ])
  end

  post '/datas.json' do
    data = JSON.parse request.body.read.to_s
    200
  end
end
```

**config.ru**:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8; mode:ruby; -*-

require './app.rb'
run App
```

Comment: thnx. For now, this is a static .json file and this is not recording anything when i POST. I just wanted to check in the console that the POST was effective. Then it's going to be plugged to a server and handle dynamic datas. So I suppose my error is coming from this. what do you think ?

Comment: @akonsu is right, @desgnl your problem is that url in `$resource`object is pointed to a file - datas.json, for retrieving data it works but not for saving, because the only thing `$save() method` does is sending POST request with according data to the specified url. So you need some back-end to handle this request and send a response as @akonsu have illustrated above. In this case you will have no error.